# How to pass a file as a parameter in the web service call in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad

I have a file stored locally which i want to upload to a sharepoint server using "CopyInToItems" web service of copy.asmx. I have to pass the file as an NSStream.
i can figure out how to do it ?

```
<!--Request-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http>
<soap:Body>
<CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<SourceUrl>-------local path of the file-------</SourceUrl><DestinationUrls>
<string>-------server path where the file needs to be uploaded--------</string>
</DestinationUrls>
<Fields>
<FieldInformation Type="Invalid" Id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
</Fields>
<Stream>
----File Stream----
 </Stream>
 </CopyIntoItems>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually u need not use NSSTREAM. you can convert the locally stored file into NSDATA using,

```
NSMutableData *filedata=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:localPath]] ;
```

then convert this NSDATA into an NSSTRING using base-64 encoding.
as base-64 encoding cannot be done directly in IOS here is a function for doing that.

```
   - (NSString *) base64StringFromData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length {
            unsigned long ixtext, lentext;
            long ctremaining;
            unsigned char input[3], output[4];
            short i, charsonline = 0, ctcopy;
            const unsigned char *raw;
            NSMutableString *result;

            lentext = [data length]; 
            if (lentext < 1)
                return @"";
            result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: lentext];
            raw = [data bytes];
            ixtext = 0; 

            while (true) {
                ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
                if (ctremaining <= 0) 
                    break;        
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
                    unsigned long ix = ixtext + i;
                    if (ix < lentext)
                        input[i] = raw[ix];
                    else
                        input[i] = 0;
                }
                output[0] = (input[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
                output[1] = ((input[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((input[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
                output[2] = ((input[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((input[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
                output[3] = input[2] & 0x3F;
                ctcopy = 4;
                switch (ctremaining) {
                    case 1: 
                        ctcopy = 2; 
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        ctcopy = 3; 
                        break;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++)
                    [result appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", base64EncodingTable[output[i]]]];

                for (i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++)
                    [result appendString: @"="];

                ixtext += 3;
                charsonline += 4;

                if ((length > 0) && (charsonline >= length))
                    charsonline = 0;
            }     
            return result;
        }
```

now call this function and pass the NSDATA of your file that you had created before as a parameter.

```
NSString *stream=[self base64StringFromData:filedata length:[filedata length] ];
```

now you can pass this string as a parameter in your web service call